# How to change order of elements based on browser size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three buttons that are stacked horizontally. Each button, when clicked, shows a div element. When the browser is resized to a mobile view, I want the elements to stack vertically. This occurs by default, but I would like to stack the div element directly underneath the button it is associated with.

**This is what I want to display** (desktop left, mobile right):

[image: Correct desktop view]
[image]

This is what I get (desktop left, mobile right):

[image: Correct desktop view]
[image: Incorrect mobile view]

Here's the basic HTML. If I move the associated divs directly underneath the buttons, it looks fine on mobile but incorrect on desktop.

```
<button onclick="updateValue(1)">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="updateValue(2)">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="updateValue(3)">Button 3</button>
<div id="div-1"><span>This is div 1!</span></div>
<div id="div-2"><span>This is div 2!</span></div>
<div id="div-3"><span>This is div 3!</span></div>
```

I did try to use floats on the buttons but I couldn't get the desired output. Here is a fiddle showing what I have right now.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gfLfb6of/)

So how do I order the elements button + button + button > div on desktop, and button > div > button > button on mobile?

Comment: Have you considered using Boostrap column ordering? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering - Or, failing that, you could see *how they did it*

Comment: @KenKinder I have not considered it but I'm certainly open to it. Do you think you could post a working example using the fiddle provided?

Comment: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is what you need!

Comment: Raphael Parent, I'd be interested in seeing a flexbox example accomplishing this - would you mind putting together a quick fiddle?

Comment: @RaphaelParent I used Flexbox and that seems to be the best solution here. Feel free to post an answer with an example and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Lefka I add flexbox example. Think this is more convenient as static div elements.

Comment: It seems less convenient to have to give each element a unique class name and then manually order them in your CSS accordingly. That removes the ability to have a dynamic number of elements without having to adjust your CSS. It also requires twice as much CSS. Is there a way to accomplish this with flexbox that doesn't resort to that?

Comment: That only applies to your specific example though. For the general question of how to change element order, flexbox is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lefka here is an example using flexbox model.
When you resize the example in full page view to window less than 420px the elements will be reordered the way you expected.
Hope it help you to figure out your needs.

```js
function updateValue(newValue) {
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
    var element = document.getElementById("div-" + i);
    element.className = "";
    if (newValue === i) {
      element.className = "show";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

[id^="div-"] {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  
  .button-1 {
    order: 0;
  }
  
  .button-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .button-3 {
    order: 4;
  }
  
  #div-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  #div-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  
  #div-3 {
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <button class="button-1" onclick="updateValue(1)">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button-2" onclick="updateValue(2)">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button-3" onclick="updateValue(3)">Button 3</button>
  <div id="div-1"><span>This is div 1!</span></div>
  <div id="div-2"><span>This is div 2!</span></div>
  <div id="div-3"><span>This is div 3!</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, move each div under its respective button.

```
<button onclick="updateValue(1)">Button 1</button>
<div id="div-1"><span>This is div 1!</span></div>
<button onclick="updateValue(2)">Button 2</button>
<div id="div-2"><span>This is div 2!</span></div>
<button onclick="updateValue(3)">Button 3</button>
<div id="div-3"><span>This is div 3!</span></div>
```

Then using CSS media queries, you can position the div absolutely below the row of buttons at desktop sizes, and then leave it positioned normally at mobile sizes.

```
button {
  display: block;
}
div {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  button {
    display: inline;
  }
  .show {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle with a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/shanecavaliere/79obb0yv/).

Answer (score 0):

And you can add a new DIV?

```html
<div>
<button onclick="updateValue(1)">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="updateValue(2)">Button 2</button>
<button onclick="updateValue(3)">Button 3</button>
</div>
<div id="div-1"><span>This is div 1!</span></div>
<div id="div-2"><span>This is div 2!</span></div>
<div id="div-3"><span>This is div 3!</span></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can add a new div. I don't see how that would solve the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Put Button1 and Div1 into a container div together with width=button's width and overflow set to visible. Repeat for other buttons if necessary. Widen divs if needed.

```
<div id=superContainer>
    <div id=subContainer1>
        <button onclick="updateValue(1)">Button 1</button>
        <div id="div-1"><span>This is div 1!</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id=subContainer2>
        <button onclick="updateValue(2)">Button 2</button>
        <div id="div-2"><span>This is div 2!</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id=subContainer3>
        <button onclick="updateValue(3)">Button 3</button>
        <div id="div-3"><span>This is div 3!</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateValue(div)
{
  $('DIV > DIV').hide();
  $('#div-'+ div).show()
}
```

```css
.parent{position:relative}

DIV > DIV{display:none; position:absolute}


@media (max-width: 480px) {
  DIV > DIV{display:none; position:relative}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
<button onclick="updateValue(1)">Button 1</button>
<div id="div-1"><span>This is div 1!</span></div>
<button onclick="updateValue(2)">Button 2</button>
<div id="div-2"><span>This is div 2!</span></div>
<button onclick="updateValue(3)">Button 3</button>
<div id="div-3"><span>This is div 3!</span></div>
</div>
```